# How do I suppress string interpolation issues in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following code:

`address = "#{(article/"div.address").inner_html.strip_html.squish}"`

(using Hpricot)

And in some instances...

`address = "#{(article/"div.address").inner_html.strip_html.squish}"`

...is *nil*

I would like the script to keep chugging along, possibly replacing nil with an empty string.

Any tips?

### Edit

I have traced the problem better to:

`puts "#{link[0].to_s}\n" unless link.empty?`

(.backtrace points to this particular line in the source.)

So the *revised* question is: why doesn't that line just not get parsed? Why does it throw an error? I thought that using `unless` will just skip it...

Comment: You are doing `link.empty?` rather than `link[0].empty?`, if link is for example `['']` then `link.empty?` is false yet `link[0].empty?` is true so depending on what link may look like you may need something else.

Comment: Also, nil doesn't respond to `empty?`

Comment: So you need `link[0].to_s.empty?` I think. What is the error? Note that `link.empty?` will throw error if `link` is nil.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `.nil?`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for the support and helpful tips, in the end it was a matter of using the proper method, I ended up solving my problem by using:

`unless uri.query.nil?`

But I did come to make use of both `.to_s` and `try` in my source, and I wish I could pick two answers as the right one!

Answer (score 2):

Use `:to_s` method:

```
nil.to_s == ''
```

Comment: How do you mean exactly? The following doesn't work: 

```title = "#{(article/"a span.listingTitle").inner_html.strip_html.squish.to_s}"
```

Comment: (article/"a span.listingTitle")

Comment: But `(article/"a span.listingTitle").inner_html` returns `""`. Are you sure?

Comment: You're right, in the end I traced it to:

`puts "#{link[0].to_s}\n" unless link.empty?`

I will revise my question...

Answer (score 0):

Is `try` what you are looking for? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

Comment: They have plans to add it in Ruby as well, but it's not there yet. But, as always, it's easy to add - here's the simplest implementation (no block support): http://ozmm.org/posts/try.html

Comment: Cool thanks, in the end I used `unless uri.query.nil?` -- but I will give it a look for an alternative.